# REST how to pass empty path parameter?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I'm building `REST` web app using `Netbean 7.1.1 Glassfish 3.1.2`

I have 2 URL:

```
"http://myPage/resource/getall/name"  (get some data by name)

"http://myPage/resource/getall" (get all data)
```

When client sends request using first URL, the servlet below is called and do some process.

```
@Path("getall/{name}")
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Object Getall(@PathParam("name") String customerName) {
      //here I want to call SQL if customerName is not null. is it possible???
}
```

But I also want second URL to call this servlet.

I thought the servlet would be called and I can just check customerName == null and then call different SQL and so on.

But when client sends request using second URL (i.e. without path parameter), the servlet is not being called because the URL does not have {name} path parameter.

Is it not possible to call second URL and invoke the servlet above?

One alternative I can think of is to use `query parameter`:

```
http://myPage/resource/getall?name=value
```

Maybe I can parse it and see if `"value"` is null then take action accordingly..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can specify a regular expression for your Path Parameter 
(see [2.1.1. @Path](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e104)).

If you use `.*` matches both empty and non empty names 
So if you write:

```
@GET
@Path("getall/{name: .*}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Object Getall(@PathParam("name") String customerName) {
      //here I want to call SQL if customerName is not null. is it possible???
}
```

it will match both "http://myPage/resource/getall" and "http://myPage/resource/getall/name".

Comment: Hi! What if situation is next: 
"http://myPage/resource/getall/name?type=json"
"http://myPage/resource/getall?type=json"
The solution above doesn't work.

Comment: @Andrew please create a new question. Without any context it's not possible to answer the question.

Comment: It only works with host/getall/ and host/getall/name, but not host/getall. My Jersey is 2.23.2

Comment: @willy_z That's what's expected. The static part or the path matched is `getall/` containing the trailing slash.  If you want also to match `host/getall` you'll need to modify the regexp to match both for example  `@Path("{\\/getall|\\/getall\\/name: .*}")` (not tested) see [JAX-RS Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-1.1-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/jax_rs-1_1-mrel-spec.pdf) for details about the supported regular expressions.

Answer (score -2):

```
@GET
@Path("getall{name:(/[^/]+?)?}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Object Getall(@PathParam("name") String customerName) {
  //here I want to call SQL if customerName is not null. is it      

 possible??? 
  }
```

Comment: match both with or without name ,